# Upload Multiple Files From DIfferent Folders

Tags: php, file-upload, html

complete amateur here.

I am pretty much doing the exact process outlined [here](https://daveismyname.blog/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-input-with-html-5-and-php) to upload multiple files with PHP and HTML5. This is working correctly for me and I am able to upload multiple files. However, it is not quite what I want. It seem my files have to be in the same folder, so I can do this process

browse -> select files -> click accept -> upload

but what I would like to do is

browse -> select file(s) -> click accept -> click browse -> select a file(s) -> click accept -> upload.

What could I implement to achieve this goal? Please let me know if there is more information I can provide.

Comment: create a javascript global array variable. Browse and select files - the selections are added to the global array. When the `upload` button is clicked, process that global array variable

Comment: Use something like https://fineuploader.com/demos.html so you can just push the files to an array.

Comment: I apologize for being such an amateur, but if either of you would like to post an answer and elaborate on your comments I will gladly accept. As is, I don’t follow your recommendations. Thanks!

Comment: To be more precise, I don't really understand the role javascript plays. I know the project I have been assigned to work on (a web application) uses javascript, php, html and sql but I don't know how the javascript fits in. I have gotten used to the php, sql and html so I have a good idea of what each is used for and how they interact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment made, a global variable is used ( in this instance it is an instance of a `FormData` object rather than a simple array ). Event handlers are established for the `file` selection field and for the `upload` button. The event handler for the `file` field simply appends selected files to the global `FormData` object and updates the html to display a count of files so far selected.

The event handler for the `upload` button itself invokes a very basic Ajax function that sends the `FormData` object to the server ( in this case it is the same page but could be an entirely different script )

The PHP at the top of the page gives a quick example of how one would process the `$_FILES` array... there is much more work required to complete the process server side - good luck!

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES ) ){
        ob_clean();

        /* 
            process the uploaded files
            --------------------------

            In the actual LIVE version you will want to check that
            each file is legitimate and of the correct type before
            saving to it's final location & possibly logging the 
            upload in the database.

            check if there were errors
            check filesize
            check filetype
            check is_uploaded_file
            check if already exists
            etc etc

            For demonstration of the upload process this script ONLY
            echoes back the details of the files uploaded.

            YOU will need to do the image processing here.... 

        */

        /* example */
        $output=array();
        $files=(object)$_FILES[ 'files' ];

        foreach( $files->name as $i => $void ){
            $name = $files->name[$i];
            $size = $files->size[$i];
            $type = $files->type[$i];
            $tmp  = $files->tmp_name[$i];
            $error= $files->error[$i];

            $output[]=array('name'=>$name,'size'=>$size,'type'=>$type);
        }
        exit( json_encode( $output ) );
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Browse multiple locations</title>
        <script>
            (function(){
                function ajax(url,payload,callback){
                    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 )callback.call( this, this.response );
                    };
                    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                    xhr.send( payload );
                }

                function callback( r ){
                    /* typically this callback would do considerably more than this... */
                    console.info( r )
                }

                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                    let fd=new FormData();
                    let oFile=document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
                    let oBttn=document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');

                    oFile.addEventListener( 'change', function(e){
                        for( var i=0; i < this.files.length; i++ ) if( this.files[ i ].type.match( 'image/.*' ) ) fd.append( 'files[]', this.files[ i ], this.files[ i ].name );
                        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=fd.getAll('files[]').length+' files in array';
                    },false );




                    oBttn.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
                        if( fd.getAll('files[]').length > 0 ) ajax.call( this, location.href, fd, callback );
                    },false );

                }, false );
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div id='count'></div>
            <input type='file' name='files' multiple />
            <input type='button' value='Upload Files' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

A slightly edited version having read your comments...Both versions should work "as-is" so if you are getting errors perhaps you can share how you have implemented this code

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES ) ){
        ob_clean();

        /* 
            process the uploaded files
            --------------------------

            In the actual LIVE version you will want to check that
            each file is legitimate and of the correct type before
            saving to it's final location & possibly logging the 
            upload in the database.

            check if there were errors
            check filesize
            check filetype
            check is_uploaded_file
            check if already exists
            etc etc

            For demonstration of the upload process this script ONLY
            echoes back the details of the files uploaded.

            YOU will need to do the image processing here.... 

        */

        /* example */
        $output=array();
        $files=(object)$_FILES[ 'files' ];

        foreach( $files->name as $i => $void ){
            $name = $files->name[$i];
            $size = $files->size[$i];
            $type = $files->type[$i];
            $tmp  = $files->tmp_name[$i];
            $error= $files->error[$i];

            $output[]=array('name'=>$name,'size'=>$size,'type'=>$type);
        }
        exit( json_encode( $output ) );
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Browse multiple locations</title>
        <script>
            (function(){
                function ajax(url,payload,callback){
                    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 )callback.call( this, this.response );
                    };
                    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                    xhr.send( payload );
                }


                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

                    let fd=new FormData();

                    const callback=function(r){
                        console.info( r )
                        let json=JSON.parse( r );
                        fd=new FormData();
                        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=Object.keys( json ).length + ' files uploaded';
                    };

                    let oFile=document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
                    let oBttn=document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');

                    oFile.addEventListener( 'change', function(e){
                        for( var i=0; i < this.files.length; i++ ) fd.append( 'files[]', this.files[ i ], this.files[ i ].name );
                        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=fd.getAll('files[]').length+' files in array';
                    },false );




                    oBttn.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
                        if( fd.getAll('files[]').length > 0 ) ajax.call( this, location.href, fd, callback );
                    },false );

                }, false );
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div id='count'></div>
            <input type='file' name='files' multiple />
            <input type='button' value='Upload Files' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Very quickly... to process the uploads. Change savedir and allowed_exts as you see fit. I would have more checks in there for various filetypes etc but time for you to step up and take over... I have a sick cat to look after.

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES ) ){
    ob_clean();

    $output=array();
    $files=(object)$_FILES[ 'files' ];

    $savedir='c:/temp/fileuploads/stack/';
    $allowed_exts=array('jpg','jpeg','png');

    foreach( $files->name as $i => $void ){
        $name = $files->name[$i];
        $size = $files->size[$i];
        $type = $files->type[$i];
        $tmp  = $files->tmp_name[$i];
        $error= $files->error[$i];

        if( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
            $ext = pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
            if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){
                if( in_array( $ext, $allowed_exts ) ){
                    $target = $savedir . '/' . $name;
                    $status = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target );
                    $output[]=$status===1 ? sprintf('The file %s was uploaded',$name) : sprintf('There was a problem uploading %s',$name);
                } else {
                    $output[]='Invalid filetype';
                }
            } else {
                $output[]='Warning: Possible file upload attack';
            }
        } else {
            $output[]='Error ' . $error;
        }
    }
    exit( json_encode( $output ) );
}
```

Comment: Found it, it is because of the line "type.match( 'image/.*' )

Comment: after commenting that out, my page shows "n files in the array" correctly, but then when I var_dump(_FILES['files']) it only shows the last thing to be added

Comment: and when I run it completely the same, uploading images it seems it never enters that php if statement

Comment: The second one works well for me upon my initial test, except the exit(json_encode(output)) should return something yes? I do not see anything from this

Comment: Ok, the first time I ran it when I clicked upload it showed me the "n files uploaded" message, but then each time I run it after I click upload and see no change. I also never see anything that comes from the $output variable. I am using wamp server and google chrome.

Comment: It is as if the upload files button does not work after the very first time I clicked it. I tried clearing my caches...

Comment: can you either post here how you have implemented the above or make a pastebin ?

Comment: I copy and pasted it into VS code text editor, saved it as test.php, went to google chrome web browser and type localhost/test.php. The first time I run it, I add 3 files and click upload and it says “3 files uploaded”, but I never see the exit output. The next time I go to test.pho through local host, I add files and it shows “3 files in array” but when I click upload, nothing happens.

Comment: Does that information help? What more can I provide to help trouble shoot. Thank you for your help

Comment: the above runs perfectly well so I cannot understand why you are having issues. Are you seeing errors in the console? Are you looking at the console?

Comment: What console do you mean?

Comment: press `F12` if you are using Chrome and choose the `console` tab

Comment: Ok, I’m on my way to work right now. I’ll try that today. Could it matter version of php I have or anything like that?

Comment: no - shouldn't matter - most of this is client side anyway

Comment: Ok, today when I click "upload" it correctly says "n files uploaded" as it should, and in the console it is showing all n of the files - but it still seems like the opening php if statement is never being accessed. I added 'echo "hello" ' inside the if statement and it does not echo hello.

Comment: Ok, after I click upload it seems that neither of the conditions in the if statement are true. Try running this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/hEtte3MU. I get the hello 1 when I run the page, but not any of the others

Comment: on loading I get `"hello 3"` and it then proceeds to work 100% correctly - I choose files from 1 folder then upload. then I select from another folder and upload... no problems... none

Comment: Perhaps the issue is just a miscommunication - after clicking upload files do you see "hello 1" or "hello 2"? I correctly see my uploads in the console from the 'console.info(r)' line but I cannot figure out how to start handling/echo-ing back information from the uploads?

Comment: Does it echo back for you?

Comment: Something is wrong - the method never changes to POST. I added var_dump($_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD]) and it is constantly "get"

Comment: `hello1` and `hello2` will never get displayed if you upload a file because of `ob_clean();`. As for the method always being `GET` when using var_dump.... is this on page load?
You do know that there is much more work required with the above code to process the uploads? This is simply the mechanism to allow browsing & selecting from multiple folders

Comment: Then after we do the xhr.send how retrieve the data to start processing it